# Azure Devops ci pipeline cannot build asp.net core project because it is in subfolder of github repo

Tags: github, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have to build an asp.net core spa project with angular frontend. So I have made two folders one for asp.net core API and other for an angular project and pushed it on GitHub. I was integrating the project with [Azure Pipe Lines](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines)!  apps in GitHub so that i can easily do ci/cd with Azure devops. Note that I want to build only the API project in the subfolder.
the github link of the project: https://github.com/lazyfahim/tritronv2
and the azure yml pipeline code : https://github.com/lazyfahim/tritronv2/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

The error message showing in the build terminal was

```
    MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The 
    current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
    ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
    ##[section]Finishing: dotnet build Release
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just edit the yaml and point dotnet build at your specific project file, e.g.:

```
steps:
- script: dotnet build SomeFolder\SomeProject.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: thank you i got it. But where i can learn this kinds of things can you provide me some resource. and thanks again

Comment: In this example you could use "dotnet -h" on your local machine, this will give you all the available dotnet commands, you can get more info on specific commands as well, e.g. for build use "dotnet build -h".

Comment: For info on Azure Devops pipelines the built in steps are good to use. Docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fpipelines%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops), try some quickstarts and then [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) goes into much more detail about all the possible options in the yaml.